# Dynamic conky variable argument

Tags: conky

I'm trying to use conky's `image` variable in a way that it read the image file path from a file or a pipe.
Something like `${image ${execp cat /home/r1y4n/.conky/imagepath.txt} -p 30,0 -s 150x150 }`
But it seems conky doesn't support nesting variables.

[here](http://conky.sourceforge.net/variables.html) says `image` variable can be modified at runtime using `$execp`

So how can I change the `image` argument in each conky loop?

I want to be able to control the image is shown from outside of conky by creating a bash script or something and setting a shortcut for it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what your final objective is. There may be better ways to do it. Are you trying to display a different image every few seconds?

Comment: @terdon: I want to control the image is shown from outside of conky (By creating a bash script or something and setting a shortcut for it);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply use a symlink and change its target as needed. For example, create a link called `conkyimage.png` which points to `~/myimages/unicorn.png`:

```
ln -s ~/myimages/unicorn.png ~/conkyimage
```

Then, in `conkyrc`, have it show that image (note the `-n`, which tells `conky` not to cache the image):

```
${image ~/conkyimage.png -p 30,0 -s 150x150 -n }
```

Finally, write a script that changes the link's target:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

## Update the link's target
ln -fs "$1" ~/conkyimage.png
```

You then run the script giving it the target image as an argument:

```
script.sh /path/to/new/image.png
```

Comment: Thank you; but what if i want to change `-s 150x150` option based on each image (So keep the aspect ratio)?

Comment: @4r1y4n I think you will have to write a lua script that conky loads for that but I have no experience with that sort of thing. Alternatively, you can write a more complex bash script that runs ImageMagick's `convert` to resize the image.