# Dynamically loading image based on function output

Tags: conky

I'm trying to load a `.png` to display a battery icon in conky. So far I've tried nesting the function call, using eval but I can't seem to find a solution.

Here is my non working conky.text:

```lua
conky.text = [[
  ${image ${lua battery_icon $battery_status $battery_icon}}
]]
```

Where my `battery_icon` function looks like this:

```lua
function conky_battery_icon(battery_status, battery_percent)
  if (battery_status == "charging")
  then
    icon = "charging-battery.png";
  else 
    ...
  end

  return("/path/to/icons/" .. icon);
end
```

I checked that the function works and I can get the correct path to the image by adding the following line to my `conky.text`:

```lua
${lua battery_icon $battery_status $battery_percent}
```

How can I use the returned path of `battery_icon` to load the file in conky's `image`?

Related question: [Dynamic conky variable argument](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193883/dynamic-conky-variable-argument/193906#193906)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than returning the path alone, you can return a fully formed conky statement to display the icon. For example, if I have a Lua function that returns an image statement, such as...

```
function conky_myimg()
    local path = "/home/David/System/Icons/StuffedTux.png";
    local s = "${image "..path.."}";
    return s;
end
```

...and I call the function in my `conky.text` with the line...

```
${lua_parse myimg}
```

...then the icon is displayed by conky.

[image: Icon displayed by conky]

Comment: What would the solution look like if you had to pass parameters to the `conky_myimg` function? Thanks for the help :)

Comment: According to `man conky`, the `lua_parse` object has the same form as the `lua` object. If that's correct, it _oughta_ be `${lua_parse myimg param1 param2 ...}`, and in your particular case it _should_ be `${lua_parse battery_icon $battery_status $battery_icon}`. (Hopefully, the man file's correct.)

Comment: Incidentally, to reduce or eliminate the need for passing parameters, you can use `conky_parse` within your Lua function to access info from conky. For example, `local p = conky_parse("$battery_percent");` assigns the battery percentage value to p. Take a look at `man conky` for more details.

Comment: That's what I'm currently working on but it seems like the parameters are being passed as a string to the function. Using `${lua_parse battery_icon $battery_status $battery_icon}` and printing `battery_status` in the `conky_battery_icon` function outputs `$battery_status` rather than its value

Comment: I'll spend more time in the man page and attempt the conky_parse solution!

Comment: I don't see a battery status object in the man page, so I'm guessing that to do what you want, you'll probably need to use `conky_parse($battery)` and then parse out the status from the resulting string. Good luck!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99410/discussion-between-phil-and-david-yockey).

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested it, but I'd try adding `lua` to your `conky.text`, where it would then read...

```
conky.text = [[
  ${image ${lua battery_icon $battery_status $battery_icon}}
]]
```

Comment: This is one of the things I tried but unfortunately conky still tries to run image with `${lua battery_icon $battery_status $battery_icon}` and fails with a parsing error. Something along the lines of `image can't read ${lua ...`

Comment: Ah. I see you've edited the question to include that bit. Good move.